# Sql query to fetch the max word count in a column

Tags: sql

I have a table with 3 columns. How do I query the column to get the words that appear the most in the column alone?

```
ID  Name   Age

#A  Gersh   9
#A  Marn    9  
#A  Drake   9 
#A  Hayford 2
```

My query should return the first 3 rows since 9 appears the most.

**SQL**

```
Select * from table group by age
```

Comment: What you are looking for is the `mode` of age (the value that appears the most). Some DBs (eg. Oracle) have this function built in, otherwise knowing the term can help you find a lot of solutions online.

Answer (score 1):

use max()

```
select * from t where age= ( select max(age) from t)
```

or use `rank()` which sopported by most dbms

```
 select ID Name  Age from 
(
 select *,rank()over(order by age desc) rn from t
) a where rn=1
```

or you can use below if you need the most similar age occurred rows need

```
with cte as
(
select 'A' as n ,9 as age
union all
select 'B',9
union all
select 'C',9
union all
select 'D',2
)
 select n as name ,age from (
 select *,
 count(*) over(partition by age order by age) as cnt
 from cte
 ) t where cnt= ( select max(cnt) from
   (
   select *,
  count(*) over(partition by age order by age) as cnt
  from cte
   )a

      )
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3c001cf5435e7493f77b63c6abd3a283)

Comment: The first 2 options (`max` and `rank`) only works because the value that appears the most happens to be the max. They are technically wrong. The last option (with `count`) is the right one, but the `order by` is not needed and if you carry on with ctes instead if nested queries you can simplify your query a lot.